# How can I access a variable in one block of PHP code in another block of PHP code in the same file?

Tags: php, html, function, output

I have something like this:

PHP code at the start:

```
 <?php
 $variable="example";
 ?>
```

Then HTML code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
```

Then again PHP:

```
 <?php
 // code comes here, and I want to access variable $variable here.
 ?>
```

And then HTML code ends:

```
 </body>
 </html>
```

Is it possible to do this somehow? I don't want to create another file; I need to do this in this file.

Comment: How about, try it and see? Yes, it'll work.

Answer (score 4):

### Not Required unless if you are accessing it under functions ( as it will lose their scope)

**`test1.php`**

```
<?php
$var = 1;


//.. your code...
?>

<html>.....

<?php
echo $var; // prints 1
```

whereas the below code won't work...

```
<?php
$var = 1;

function displayVar()
{
echo $var; // You will get a notice .. ! 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do what you stated above and it will work.

```
<?php
$variable = 'Hello';
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $variable; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The above example will display a simple webpage with 'Hello' as the content. This is one of best strength of PHP actually.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo ($variable);
```

or

```
print($variable);
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is the same file, yes it is possible, unless the variable is in a function. But this is a very simple question, that you could have tested yourself.